# Is there a way remove index.php in Laravel without changing .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, laravel, .htaccess

In our production server they have **disabled .htaccess** file to load in apache configuration for some security reasons, due to this all the URL's are added with **index.php** in addition.

Problem **image url** and **curl request** is not properly working due to the index.php added in addition to the url.

Is there are other way to do this.Even if I correct the CURL request It will help me.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to check if there is `DirectoryIndex` configuration added to the virtual host configuration for your production server. If not try to add the following:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

Comment: I removed the text in my answer which implied for no use of htaccess. However, you may try to add the htaccess content to your virtualhost configuration file. That may help.